# how to generate an animation of a plane & its normal map out of image and its normal map

Tags: animation, texturing, normal-map

I have an 2D color image(added it as a texture to a plane) & its relevant normal map.
i'd like to create an animation of a camera going around, as an output i want the rendered color image and its rendered normal map.

1. i used the Principled BSDF Node to add the texture & normal map as a material to a plane.
2. i created the curve of the animation as set the camera pose properly.
3. the color image animation is correctly rendered, but normal map is not. please help.

Thanks